# KDE Application Platform update issue

Tags: 18.04, kde, ubuntu-gnome

Peace. Lately I have a persistent KDE Application Platform update prompt, that cannot be dismissed.

[image: update prompt]

[image: update issue]

I'm unsure how to debug this. My Google searches on the topic point to some flatpak types of information, however nothing corresponds. I'd mostly be taking shots in the dark.

Clicking into the tile shows me something about a runtime for kde.

[image: kde runtime]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had the same error... solution found at

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/d95jh3/unable_to_update_gnome_application_platform/

That's a Flatpak runtime, i.e. a collection of libraries and tools used by apps that were installed via Flatpak. One of the important properties of Flatpak is that you can install and use apps that need libraries from e.g. Gnome 3.34, while your system uses a much older version of Gnome (or an entirely different DE). So in this case, you'd be upgrading that runtime, not the version of Gnome that's running as your DE.

Concerning the error: Since it's complaining that the org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08 runtime isn't installed, try manually installing it

```
flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08
```

and then trying the update again

```
flatpak update
```

Comment: Peace @user1031817 and thank you!